# Unable to run Genymotion wizard in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, emulation, genymotion

I have installed eclipse plugin for genymotion.

OS:ubuntu 14.04LTS

Ram:4Gb

processor:i5 3rd gen intel

When I try to launch Genymotion, it doesn't start:

> Run Genymotion wizard: failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "/home/vishal/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20131030/sdk//genymotion": error=2,
>   No such file or directory

Can any one tell me how to find this directory?

Comment: Have you installed genymotion itself also or just the eclipse plugin? Look on genymotion.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the issue of plugin and old virtual box at that time after then i just uninstall old virtual box.

and download new [virtual box](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_4_2) in Ubuntu by terminal.
its work.